# Polynomials that are non-negative outside the $L_2$ unit ball

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, real-algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the set of all bivariate polynomials over the reals of degree at most two, that are non-negative outside the $L_2$ unit ball. Are all the polynomials in $\mathcal{P}$ one of the following forms:
$$p(x,y) = (ax+by+c)^2 \text{ or}$$
$$p(x,y) = \frac{(x-a_1)^2}{b_1^2} + \frac{(y-a_2)^2}{b_2^2} - 1 ?$$

If $p$ can be factorized into two different (upto constant factors) linear polynomials, then it will necessarily be negative somewhere be outside the unit ball. So, $p$ must be the square of a linear polynomial or irreducible.

If all irreducible polynomials ($n=2$, $d=2$, over reals) have the second type above (or a scalar multiple of it), then we are done. Is that true?

**Edit 1**: Not all irreducible polynomials ($n=2$, $d=2$, over reals) are of the second type above. For example, $x^2 -y^2 + 1$ is irreducible. But my original question, about $\mathcal{P}$, still stands.

**Edit 2**: As pointed out by obscurans in the comment, these are not the only two kinds polynomials in $\mathcal{P}$. It also seems that a polynomial in $\mathcal{P}$ does not even have to be the sum of squares of finitely many linear polynomials plus a (possibly negative) constant. $500y^2+200x^2-400xy+x-10$ seems to be a polynomial that cannot be wriiten as sum of squares of linear polynomials plus a constant (I could not prove this though). But it's in $\mathcal{P}$.

**Edit 3**: As Gerry Myerson pointed out in his comment, $500y^2+200x^2-400xy+x-10$ is in fact a sum of squares of linear polynomials plus a (negative) constant. Now I wonder if all polynomials in $\mathcal{P}$ are of this form...

Comment: What about adding your two forms together? "Non-negative outside the $L_2$ unit ball" is conserved. You have at least the positive cone of a vector space.

Comment: Isn't it $(10x-20y)^2+(x+(1/2))^2+(10y)^2+(\sqrt{99}x)^2-(41/4)$?

Comment: Consider a second degree polynomial. 
$p(x,y) = a x^2 + by^2 + c xy + d x + e y + z$ 
One necessary condition is that $p(x,y)$ be positive for the points $(x,y)$ such that $x^2 + y^2$ goes to infinity.  In those cases, the second order part dominates the first order part, so it is equivalent to the positivity of $ a x^2 + b y^2 + c  x y$ . This requires $a + b \geq 0$ and $a^2 + b^2 - \frac{c^2}{4} \geq 0$ .

Another necessary condition is that the conic section given by $p(x,y) = 0$, (which will be either null or an ellipse, assuming above inequalities hold), lies in the unit ball.

Comment: The two conditions are also sufficient, but the second one would be really tricky to characterize in algebraic terms.

Comment: Edit: I meant to say $a b - \frac{c^2}{4} \geq 0$, not $a^2 +  b^2 - \frac{c^2}{4} \geq 0$ .

Comment: @user3257842 agreed - I was also trying to work out using polars, so you get $(a\cos^2(\theta)+b\sin^2(\theta)+c\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta))t^2+(d\cos(\theta)+e\sin(\theta))t+z$ needs to have roots within $[-1,1]$ if at all, which means, normalized to $t^2+b't+c'$, that (1) $b'\leq2\sqrt{c'}$ or (2) $|b'|+c\geq-1\;\wedge\;|b'|\leq2$ for all $\theta$

Comment: Since there are no answers yet, there is no need to append Edit sections.  Merely refine the question and flag the orphaned comments as "no longer needed"

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, I don't understand your comment about propositional logic.

Comment: @MathewsBoban Because it was a stupid comment.  I meant *predicate* logic.  Translating to a universally-quantified formula.

Comment: $ \mathcal{P} = \{ax^2 + by^2 + cxy + dx +ey + f : \forall x_0 \forall y_0  \text{ with } x_0^2 +y_0^2 > 1, ax_0^2 + by_0^2 + cx_0y_0 + dx_0 +ey_0 + f \geq 0 \}$
Is this what you asked?

Comment: @MathewsBoban Something like that, but without commas and English.  Something that Mathematica could digest.  I think you need a material implication in there.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, of course it's not syntactically precise First-Order logic. I know how to write it precisely, if you are testing my logic knowlege. Please explain what you need it for.

Comment: @MathewsBoban You could feed the universally-quantified formula into Mathematica and use [Reduce](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) to obtain a quantifier-free formula.